# Get last part of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the last part of the url in a pretty weird html structure. Don't ask why it's built that way. There is a very good reason behind it.

The html looks like this

```
<li class="lifilter"><input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="Cheeks...">
   <label for="Cheeks...">
      <a href="/collections/cheeks">Cheeks</a>
   </label>
</li>
```

and the js i'm trying to use

```
$('#Cheeks... label a').each(function(){
      var lasturl = $(this).attr('href');
      var urlsplit = url.split("/");
      var finalvar = urlsplit[4];
      $(this).addClass(finalvar);
});
```

edit: damn.. i can only post once every 90 minutes.
here is updated question with updated html

```
 <li class="lifilter">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="Cheeks...">
    <label for="Cheeks...">
         <a href="/collections/cheeks" class="cheeks">Cheeks</a>
    </label>
 </li>
```

and the js code i'm trying to use (from a previous answer)

```
$('.lifilter').each(function(){
      $(this).find(".filtercheck").next('label').find('a').each(function(){
         var lasturl = $(this).attr('href');
         var urlsplit = lasturl.split("/");
         console.log(urlsplit);
         var finalvar = urlsplit.pop();
         console.log('Adding class: ' + finalvar);
         $(this).addClass(finalvar);
      });
 });
```

Comment: what's the error you have encountered?

Comment: add this urlsplit [ urlsplit.length -1 ]

Comment: no related errors.  @unikom, could you plz show it in a code? I'm sill learning and evening sleepiness doesn't really help figuring it out either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it appears no one here attempted to try the solution here before posting.

First things first `cheeks...`. This is a tricky ID to find (You have to escape the periods). The `label` is also not part of the internal html where ID is `cheeks...`, so we need to find the adjacent element and look the `a` anchor tag you're looking for.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Cheeks\\.\\.\\.').next('label').find('a').each(function(){
          var lasturl = $(this).attr('href');
          var urlsplit = lasturl.split("/");
         console.log(urlsplit);
          var finalvar = urlsplit.pop();
        console.log('Adding class: ' + finalvar);
          $(this).addClass(finalvar);
    });
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6s4ua5rc/1/) is a working jsfiddle with the solution.

Comment: Great answer,  *nbrooks* noticed the incorrect selector too and since this is using `.pop()` as I did in my answer, I didn't see much point in correcting the selector as the answer would be the same as yours.

Comment: If you post a bit more of what you're trying to find (You only posted one element with your example pointing at ID, so that's all I could base my answer off of), I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah. that was my mistake. I'll post a new question in a few minutes, since that would be kind of unfare to do it here

Comment: I don't see any difference in the HTML, and the javascript code you posted should work for what it appears you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

keeping it simple like your code you'd do

```
finalvar = urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1];
```

in case you don't want the base url as a valid return then:

```
finalvar = ( urlsplit.length > 1 ? urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1] : "" );
```

replace "" with your preferred error/default return

you could also try to find the index of the last '/' and do a substring.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ue20u1ux/1/)**

```
var URI = 'www.example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/',
    parts = URI.split('/'),
    lastPart = parts.pop() == '' ? parts[parts.length - 1] : parts.pop();
//RESULT : "sub3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the last section of a path (i.e. everything after the last `/`) by using a regular expression:

`text.replace(/.*\//g, "")`

This will remove all of the text before a slash, as well as the slash itself. You'll also notice that your selector wasn't matching any elements; you're looking for labels nested within inputs, which doesn't match the html you posted (and isn't a valid DOM structure). An appropriate selector would be `.lifilter label a`, since the `<label>` is within the `<li>`.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.lifilter label a').each(function() {
      // strip everything up to and including the last forward slash
      var path = $(this).attr('href').replace(/.*\//g, "");

      $(this).addClass(path);

    });
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
a.cheeks:after {
  content: "  (className = 'cheeks')";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="lifilter">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="Cheeks...">
  <label for="Cheeks...">
    <a href="/collections/cheeks">Cheeks</a>
  </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the last section of url for example **activation code** or **id**.You can try this.

```
var url = 'www.abc.com/code=12345',
    parts = url.split('='),
    lastPart = parts.pop()

//lastPart = 12345
```